How bodhisattva avoid being enlightened before fulfilling paramita
It's said, someone wishing to become Lord Buddha, doesn't achieve Nirvana until he fulfill his Paramita and goes to last birth (in Theravada tradition).
So, while he fulfill his Paramita,

does he consciously do that (avoiding the Nirvana)?

(like stopping meditation mid session thinking I should stop now).
or

it happens automatically (like, he loses the ability to achieve Nirvana while fulfilling Paramita)?

(if, this is the method, that implies that he loses the ability to achieve Nirvana midway, because of a past life decision).
or

the midway decision occur randomly and from like 100 beings who fulfil Paramita to achieve state of Lord Buddha, some give up or randomly achieve Nirvana as an Arahant and some give up or randomly achieve Nirvana as a Pacceka Buddha. And, others achieve state of Lord Buddha.

So, what is the process here?
Thanks .

Related for Mahayana: How do Bodhisattva vow takers avoid stream entry?

I recall reading a biography of the late renowned Ajahn Mun of the Forest tradition. In it, Ajahn Mun mentioned about renouncing such a vow.

Ãcariya Mun related that in ages past he had made a similar resolution – in his case, a solemn vow to become a Buddha. As with Ãcariya Sao, intensifying his efforts at meditation caused Ãcariya Mun to recollect this long-standing intention, and this underlying attachment made him reluctant to strive for the attainment of Nibbãna in his present life. Ãcariya Mun renounced his vow to be a Buddha only after he began practicing dhutanga kammaååhãna, for he then realized that its fulfillment would take far too long. It required eons of traversing the round of saÿsãra: being born, growing old, becoming ill, and dying over and over again, enduring misery and pain indefinitely.

Furthermore, he said that he could easily abandon the vow because it was not yet firmly fixed that he could not detach from it. I think this is the reason why it is important that such vows (to become a Samma Sambuddha) needs to be made in the presence of a living fully Enlightened Buddha after making an appropriate offering.
This appeared to be the case for our Buddha Gotama when he declared his intention after making an offering to the Buddha Dipankara as a Brahmin ascetic named Sumedha (note: if I recall correctly the Bodhisattva vow was made in an even earlier life before the encounter with Dipankara). But declaring the vow (not sure if it was done verbally or mentally) after making the offering to the Buddha Dipankara and having him made a prophecy (that Buddha Gotama would appear in future) appeared to seal the outcome for our Buddha.
From the biography above and according to the Mahayana tradition, it would seem that there are many beings who had made this vow and just as many who renounce or give up their vows subsequently. So, to answer the question:

If the vow was taken up light-heartedly without serious and genuine efforts towards practising the paramitas then it would be forgotten like empty promises.
In the process of spiritual development, those who practised seriously and find themselves on the path to Nirvana will inevitably find themselves hindered (to be enlightened) and recollect the vows they had made. They can decide whether to renounce their vows and strive towards Nirvana instead. But this option is only possible if point 3 below did not happen.
For those who had made the appropriate offerings and received a prediction from one or more previous Buddha(s), it appeared that there is only one choice i.e. to continue till they reach Buddhahood.


Perhaps the vow to become a Sammasambuddha in the future, reinforces self-view, thus preventing stream entry.

I think the vow is only part of the process. The offering to a living Buddha is equally important. A Buddha is fully accomplished in the workings of karma. It is only after carefully confirming the karmic potential of the candidate to become a Buddha then only a prophecy is announced. I believe there are just as many who made the vow and offerings to a living Buddha but never received any prediction.

Here's an analogy.
The Buddha is like Einstein who discovered the Theory of Relativity. He's the only one, and there's no one else like him.
The stream enterer is the physics bachelor's degree graduate who studied relativity and passed. He has proven understanding of the breadth of physics, but not the depth. He has entered the physics academic stream.
The once returner is the physics master's degree graduate. He needs to return to university one more time to do his doctorate.
The never returner is the physics doctorate graduate. He doesn't have to return to university again to do a degree, but he still needs to build up his research portfolio and experience.
The Arahant is the tenured physics professor. He has reached the peak of his career.
Einstein obviously never studied relativity for his degrees because he is the one who discovered it and instantly became the first professor of it.
Similarly, the Bodhisattva Siddhartha Gautama was never a stream enterer, once-returner or never-returner before his lifetime as Prince Siddharta Gautama.
He became fully enlightened and instantly became an Arahant and Sammasambuddha only on the night of his awakening.
Please see MN 4 on the three knowledges he obtained on the night of his enlightenment. If he were a stream enterer, he would have had the third knowledge of the Four Noble Truths long before this night.
How did he avoid enlightenment before perfecting his paramis? This I do not know and asked it in this question, directed at Mahayana practitioners: How do Bodhisattva vow takers avoid stream entry?
The answer would have to be quite different for Theravada compared to Mahayana, because Arahantship is the final stage for Theravada but only an intermediate stage to Buddhahood for Mahayana.

In the Pali Suttas, the term 'bodhisatta' is found in many suttas, such as MN 4, MN 19, SN 12.10 & SN 12.65, where it simply refers to 'the being intent on awakening'. It is only a late genre sutta, such as MN 123, where 'bodhisatta' is associated with past lives, in the same way 'bodhisatta' was used in the Jataka Tales, composed around 300 years after the Buddha's passing.
Similarly, the concept of 'bodhisatta' perfecting 'parami' is not found in the Pali Suttas of the Lord Buddha's Words. Wikipedia says:

The Theravāda teachings on the pāramīs can be found in canonical books (Jataka tales, Apadāna, Buddhavamsa, Cariyāpiṭaka) and post-canonical commentaries written to supplement the Pāli Canon that therefore might not be an original part of the Theravāda teachings. The oldest parts of the Sutta Piṭaka (for example, Majjhima Nikāya, Digha Nikāya, Saṃyutta Nikāya and the Aṅguttara Nikāya) do not mention the pāramīs as a category...
Pāramitā

The question is related to later (illogical) ideas about Buddhism (folks stories); therefore the question cannot be answerered. Bodhisattva perfecting paramita over many lifetimes is not a teaching of Lord Buddha.

I am just asking. Not arguing. So, there's no rebirth? No Samsara?

There is a Pali sutta (i cannot remember the number) where a Non-Returner thinks about telling his uncle about enlightenment, which causes the Non-Returner to not attain Arahantship (Nibbana) because his thoughts of his 'uncle' came from 'self-view'. This shows the Bodhisatta could have not been a Non-Returner because if the Bodhisatta was a Non-Returner they would not return to the world.
To propose the Bodhisatta was a Stream-Enterer or Once-Returner also is illogical because a Stream-Enterer or Once-Returner know the Noble Eightfold Path to Awakening. However, the Pali Suttas (SN 12.65; MN 26) report the Bodhisatta searched for the Path to Awakening.
In summary, the Pali Suttas report the Bodhisatta perfected no parami. In fact, SN 6.2 literally says the Newly Awakened Buddha still had certain imperfections to be perfected.

Maybe that's the reason for taking the vow. I don't think that's a vow that can be easily be broken. Yet, Bodhisattvas can enter the deepest Prajnaparmitas (Heart Sutra) so they can most likely enter into any jhana they choose.
